# Running Gearman Workers in the Background

Tags: php, gearman

I'm using Ubuntu Natty with PHP 5.3.8. I just got Gearman working on my server.

I did a few tests with some scripts I got off the PHP Manual, and everything works ok.

However, I'd like to know if there's a way I can run the worker in the background, and also monitor it so that when I move to a multi-worker situation, I can keep track of just how many workers I've got working.

Usually, I would have to open two terminals, one for the worker and one for the client. The one for the worker becomes 'stuck' in effect after the php script is executed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok. I found a solution to my earlier problem. It involves using Supervisord to deamonize the gearman worker(s).

Here's how to install Supervisord

```
apt-get install python-setuptools
easy_install supervisor
echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Here's how to configure it (first get an init script from [here](https://gist.github.com/176149) and save it to `/etc/init.d/supervisord`), then do the following:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/supervisord
update-rc.d -f supervisord defaults
```

You then need to update your supervisor.conf file to tell supervisord which command you want to run as a daemon (of course, this would be your gearman worker). Below is just a sample of what you would add to your supervisord.conf file, you'll need to update it to your own specific situation.

```
[program:gearman]
command=/usr/bin/php php_gearman_worker.php
numprocs=1
directory=/root/gearman
stdout_logfile=/root/gearman/supervisord.log
environment=GEARMAN_USER=gearman
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=gearman
stopsignal=KILL
```

When you're done, then start supervisord i.e. `/etc/init.d/supervisord start`.

Once you do this, your Gearman worker is now active and you can now run your gearman client via the command line or with your browser.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `apt-get install supervisor` and creating `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gearman.conf` with just  `[program:gearman]` and `command=/usr/bin/php php_gearman_worker.php` was all that was needed for me.

Answer (score 5):

For background workers you can use GearmanManager by Brian Moon
https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I found another more workable way using Supervisord.

Comment: GearMan monitor and Gearman Manager together should do the trick. https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use [`screen`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/screen.1.php) to put the worker task into a detached shell:

```
screen -d -m php worker.php
```