# Running Gearman PHP workers infinitely

Tags: php, gearman

I've setup Gearman to work with PHP. Im really new to Gearman and task managing and the problem im having is that, when i close the terminal window running the worker, the process stops too. I want the PHP worker script to run forever. I don't know how to achieve this. Am i missing something from the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Gearman Manager](http://brian.moonspot.net/GearmanManager). It's designed to work as a service that you can start / stop. It's installed with [install.sh](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager/blob/master/install/install.sh).

```
/etc/init.d/gearman-manager start
/etc/init.d/gearman-manager stop
```

Comment: Thank i wrote my own lightweight gearman manager. and this was a good suggestion too

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is interested in a simpler way to handle this. Use a shell script to call the worker.php in a loop. You can also pass variables to the php cli (-rmethod)

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
php -q /path/to/worker.php -rmethod
sleep 5
done
```

Another way was to use Supervisord. [Running Gearman Workers in the Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217848/running-gearman-workers-in-the-background?rq=1)